# docker registry on localhost with nginx proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, docker

I'm trying to setup a private docker registry to upload my stuff but I'm stuck. The docker-registry instance is running on port 5000 and I've setup nginx in front of it with a proxy pass directive to pass requests on port 80 back to `localhost:5000`.

When I try to push my image I get this error:
`Failed to upload metadata: Put http://localhost:5000/v1/images/long_image_id/json: dial tcp localhost:5000: connection refused`

If I change localhost with my server's ip address in nginx configuration file I can push allright. Why would my local `docker push` command would complain about `localhost` when `localhost` is being passed from nginx.

Server is on EC2 if it helps.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure the specifics of your traffic, but I spent a lot of time using [mitmproxy](http://mitmproxy.org/) to inspect the dataflows for Docker. The Docker registry is actually split into two parts, the index and the registry. The client contacts the index to handle metadata, and then is forwarded on to a separate registry to get the actual binary data.

The Docker self-hosted registry comes with its own watered down index server. As a consequence, you might want to figure out what registry server is being passed back as a response header to your index requests, and whether that works with your config. You may have to set up the `registry_endpoints` config setting in order to get everything to play nicely together.

In order to solve this and other problems for everyone, we decided to build a hosted docker registry called [Quay](https://quay.io) that supports private repositories. You can use our service to store your private images and deploy them to your hosts.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is where they use it: https://github.com/dotcloud/docker-registry/blob/master/registry/index.py

You can just add it to the active config section in your config.yml file.

Answer (score 2):

Override X-Docker-Endpoints header set by registry with:

```
proxy_hide_header  X-Docker-Endpoints;
add_header         X-Docker-Endpoints $http_host;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you face is that the docker-registry is advertising so-called endpoints through a X-Docker-Endpoints header early during the dialog between itself and the Docker client, and that the Docker client will then use those endpoints for subsequent requests.

You have a setup where your Docker client first communicates with Nginx on the (public) 80 port, then switch to the advertised endpoints, which is probably localhost:5000 (that is, your local machine).

You should see if an option exists in the Docker registry you run so that it advertises endpoints as your remote host, even if it listens on localhost:5000.